# Multiple Cart Checkout w/Paypal

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am currently in the process of writing a custom shopping cart application, similar to Etsy but for a specialized market. We tried talking to our merchant account about whether we could accept payments on behalf of our various partners (similar to how Amazon has a single checkout process even if you order from multiple sellers) and were told not a chance because we're not big enough.

With that in mind, we need to make our process have multiple checkouts exactly like Etsy does, and along with that we will need to be able to push payments via PayPal to multiple emails (not chained payments - we just can't use their built-in store stuff because the individual PayPal ID's are different per "store"). In addition to that, we'd like to control the checkout process sort of like Etsy does where the look/feel are custom even though it's on PayPal.

How do we go about this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a really big question I'm going to give you an answer from personal experience. Each PayPal account will be given a unique key to be used in their API which is available via nuget. I am going to warn you, it is friendly if you understand json and are willing to play around. When handling multiple users you can store keys in databases and substitute when needed. You should also look into stripe because their API is know for being extremely developer friendly. I actually moved our service from PayPal to stripe. Now you can always use their system for managing shopping carts and other information. I decided to make my own infrastructure as I wanted to understand my website inside and out. Also by doing this I make them just my payment processor allowing me to switch processors without destroying my integrity. I hope this helps. Like I said this is a pretty open question

Comment: The only downside with this is we also inherit the processing fees. What we're trying to do is send them off to PayPal to make the payment (meaning the fees don't hit us) and once it's paid it comes back to us accordingly. The hard part of that is we have to push payments to numerous vendors in order to facilitate this. I did a some further poking around and it looks like PayPal's Adaptive Payments might be a good solution: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: The fees wouldn't hit you because you would be using their Api token from their account to process payments. This is a matter of trust between you and your customers. Typically its not the best move to give out your private keys to any Api. That being said if your customer trust you its not a huge deal.